# Syntax error in On Change dealing with combo box limited to 64k records Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, combobox

Looking at previous help for others here, I tried adding code below in On Change for a combo box. When I paste it in, I get a message saying the expression contains invalid syntax - may have entered an operand without an operator. I am dealing with a quick lookup that used to be fine, but now won't let me at records further down in the alphabet.  The On Change event builder wants to prepend an = sign to the code.  Here is the code:

```
Dim strRowSource As String

  strRowSource = "SELECT DISTINCTROW Maps_Subject.Token, Maps_Subject.Subject, Left$([MapTitle],100) AS [Map Title], Maps.AccessionNumber FROM Maps INNER JOIN Maps_Subject ON Maps.Token = Maps_Subject.Token"
  If Len(Me!cboSearchSubject.Text)=1 Then
     strRowSource = strRowSource & " WHERE Maps_Subject.Subject Like '" 
     strRowSource = strRowSource & Me!cboSearchSubject.Text
     strRowSource = strRowSource & "*' ORDER BY Maps_Subject.Subject, Left$([MapTitle],100)"
     Me!cboSearchSubject.RowSource = strRowSource
     Me!cboSearchSubject.DropDown
  End If
```

Comment: To help you in the future, you can always type `Debug.Print strRowSource` at any point in your code and it will print the value of your variable to the console.

Comment: So you're getting `=SELECT DISTINCTROW Maps_Subject.Token, Maps_Subject.Subject, Left$([MapTitle],100) AS [Map Title], Maps.AccessionNumber FROM Maps INNER JOIN Maps_Subject ON Maps.Token = Maps_Subject.Token WHERE Maps_Subject.Subject Like 'YourChoice*' ORDER BY Maps_Subject.Subject, Left$([MapTitle],100)` ??